# Issues rebuilding alamofire with iOS 10

Tags: ios, alamofire, ios10, carthage

I have an iOS app that worked great in iOS 9 but when I upgraded to iOS 10, I am getting an error with alamofire. When I build the app it says

```
"Module file was created using an older version of the compiler, rebuild 'Alamofire' and try again"
```

I have attempted to rebuild it by typing `carthage update` and it does rebuild the framework files but when I re-add them as embedded or linked binaries, I get the same error. How can I go about diagnosing and fixing this issue? I suspect that this isn't an iOS 10 issue in particular but more just a rebuilding that I am failing to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Change Xcode's command line tools to point to the 8 beta app:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/
```

See the [Swift 3.0 issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1316) on the Alamofire repo for more info.